# According to Catholic Church, does John the Evangelist mention the same individual Jews at 8: 31 and 8:59?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, gospel-of-john, jews

We read at Jn 8: 31:

> Then Jesus said to the Jews who had believed in him, “If you continue in my word, you are truly my disciples”

That is followed by a hot debate between the Jews and Jesus on sin, ancestry etc. Towards the end, they  pick up stones to throw at him, accusing him of blasphemy (Jn 8:59) .

One wonders whether John is describing the change of attitude of the same individual Jews whom he mentions as believers at 8:31 , towards the end of the chapter. My question therefore is: **According to Catholic Church, does John the Evangelist mention the same individual Jews at 8: 31 and 8:59?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cornelius à Lapide, S.J., commentates](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3844) that they were different:

> [Ver. 59](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=8&l=59-#x).—*Then they took up*, &c., as a blasphemer, who placed Himself above Abraham, and made Himself equal to God. Blasphemers were ordered to be stoned ([Lev. 24:16](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=3&ch=24&l=16-#x)). It is clear that these Jews were not those who were said to have believed in Him [in [v. 31](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=8&l=31-#x)] (as Theophylact supposes), but the others who were opposed to Christ. “And to what should such hardness betake itself but to stones?” says. S. Augustine (*in loc.*) “They sought to crush Him, whom, they could not understand,” says S. Gregory (*Hom.* xviii.)